# How to list dependencies for an alias?

Tags: clojure, command-line-interface

Assume I have this `config.edn`:

```clj
{:deps {org.clojure/clojure {:mvn/version "1.11.1"}}
 :aliases {:dev {:extra-deps {org.clojure/tools.namespace {:mvn/version "1.3.0"}}}}}
```

How can I list dependencies in a way that `extra-deps` from `dev` alias are included too?

```bash
$ clj -X:dev:deps list
org.clojure/clojure 1.11.1  (EPL-1.0)
org.clojure/core.specs.alpha 0.2.62  (EPL-1.0)
org.clojure/spec.alpha 0.3.218  (EPL-1.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `clj -X:deps help/doc` and scroll to the `clojure.tools.cli.api/list` function, you'll see that it supports an extra `:aliases` argument.

So you can use something like `clj -X:deps list :aliases '[:dev]'`.